# Getting Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with incompatible format error after adding Firebase Analytics Nuget

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-analytics

I am trying to enable Firebase Analytics in my Xamarin Forms project. The iOS version goes very well, however, when adding nuget packages in Android project I am getting error while building my project. I am following [Using Firebase Analytics in your Xamarin.Forms app](https://www.thewissen.io/using-firebase-analytics-in-your-xamarin-forms-app/) to enable firebase in my app. I have added

> Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics and Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl

Nugets. while running my app I am getting weired error attached in the screenshot. Clicking any of those errors takes me to a file "values.xml". In fact there are two identical values.xml files (these files are not located in my android project, but opens when clicking on the errors)

[image: VS error screen]

Comment: The error seems that you have defined rge buttonSize twice. I am not sure whether the error is caused by the FirebaseAnalytics. Could you provide more information for me to reproduce?

Comment: Well, If I add those packages in my Android project. I am getting those error. Even I couldn't update my packages now. (e.g If I want to to update Xamarin.Form.Pancake in my android project, I am getting this error). I created a new Xamarin form project and added those two packages, but now it asks for Androidx packages (AndroidX.lifecycle.liveData, AndroidXBrowser,Google.Android, AndroidX.Legacy.Support.v4). Adding those packages results in java.exe exited with code 1 error. It seems something about AndroidX or old version.

Comment: I got the AndroidX error before. When you install those packages, the error would be fixed. For the settings of AndroidX, You could check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I'm getting the same error when trying to update from the Fabric nugets to the new Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics packages. Reinstalling nuget packages does not help and so far I cannot reproduce the issue in a new project. It looks as though the auto-generated values.xml files are being generated from two different/conflicting versions of Xamarin, but I have no idea where to look for the dependency problem

Comment: @foamy yeah you are right. I am in the same situtation getting two values.xml files while adding those packages. Wendy Zang I followed that link but that's not the issue.

Comment: @ARH Be sure to let us know if you find a solution. Currently, we are simply waiting for an answer to this since we can't upgrade the packages in their current state.

Comment: @foamy yes sir.

Comment: @ARH Check the value.xml file again for the definition. I could not reproduce the error. But on my test for the Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics packages, there is no error.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT "values.xml" is not something we as developers are creating. They are auto-generated by building the solution, and two of the files have "buttonsize" defined. I have also not been able to reproduce the error in a new project. However, I am currently unable to update my packages due to this error.

Comment: @foamy Dur to can not reproduce, we only could provide some suggestions to test. Have you try to delete one of them?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I have pasted all the packages I installed in my project. The link is here in https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/402. For me it seems that those two packages are not compatible with the installed packages.

Comment: @ARH  I have installed the packages. What is the "buttonsize"? Is it something you defined in value xml?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT The file value.xml is auto generated When adding those firebase packages. I can’t produce it in new project. But I can’t add it in my current project.

Comment: @ARH Does it work in new project? If yes, use the new project instead.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Moving everything to a new project is a task that will take days. In my mind that is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @foamy Temporarily I have added AppCenter packages to look after my crashes/analytics. (I have added those packages without error, but I know this is not the solution)

Comment: @foamy finally found the solution. Please tick incremental android packaging in Android project properties->Android Options-> Use incremental Android packaging (appt2). Please refer to this link https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView/issues/153

Comment: @ARH Thanks, but I already tried that after reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/172279/error-apt1000-attribute-34imageaspectratioadjust34.html

Answer (score 1):

After switch on aapt2 for build the issue was solved for me

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with the new 116+ versions.. downgrade to version 71.xx and it solves the problem

Comment: Installing those versions results in installing others packages like Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils and Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment. After installing these two packages, I get java.exe exited with code 1 error.